# How to get the headings of a word document including their style names?

Tags: javascript, ms-word, office-js

Is there a way to get the table of contents of a Word document including the styles used in an add-in?

I'm able to get the full text of the document (including the headings), using `console.log(context.document.body.text)` but it just gives me the entire document as a string, stripping away all styles and formatting. I need to get the heading level of each heading so my add-in can check that whatever document I have open is structured correctly.

Comment: Do you mean "headers" - content at the top  of a page... Or do you mean "headings"? I suspect the latter, but both are techical terms in Word so this is confusing... In any case `Text` always returns only a string - no formatting information. Formatting information is available from a `Range` object. You might try working with the `Paragraphs` collection, which can be interated so that the `Style` format can be queried from each paragraph's range.

Comment: @CindyMeister. Please make your comment an answer. Thanks.

Comment: OK... @RickKirkham

Answer (score 1):

Any time the content of a Word document is queried using a `Text` property only the string content will be returned, stripped of all formatting information.

Formatting information is available from `Range` objects. In this case, get the `Paragraphs` collection, iterate over it and check the `Style` properties of the `Paragraph.Range` that are relevant.

Alternatively, getting the OpenXML of the body will return a string with the content as Word Open XML in the OPC flat-file format. That can be "parsed" for all kinds of information.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this work for you

I just console headers array

```
[{
key: keyValue
level: 1 // headers level
text: "Header 1 testing" // headers string
}]
```

Full Code :

```
Word.run(async function (context) {
            const paragraphs = context.document.body.paragraphs.load('items');
            const headers = [];
            const headersString = [];
            context
                .sync()
                .then(async function () {
                    await context.sync();
                    for (let i = 0; i < paragraphs.items.length; i++) {
                        const item = paragraphs.items[i];

                        context.load(item, ['text', 'style']);
                        // we can use outlineLevel 1,2,3
                        if (item.style === 'Heading 1' || item.style === 'Heading 2' || item.style === 'Heading 3') {
                            headers.push(paragraphs.items[i]);
                        }
                    }
                    console.log(headers);
                    headers.map((item) => {
                        headersString.push({
                            key: item._ReferenceId,
                            text: item.text.toString(),
                            level: item.outlineLevel,
                        });
                    });

                    console.log(headersString);
                })
                .then(context.sync);
        }).catch(function(error) {
          console.log('Error: ' + error);
          if (error instanceof OfficeExtension.Error) {
             console.log('Debug info: ' + JSON.stringify(error.debugInfo));
             console.log('Trace info: ' + JSON.stringify(error.traceMessages));
           }
        });
```